# how do I extend Lua with a static c++ library?

Tags: c++, lua

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++03 application that uses Lua 5.2.1. I would like to extend Lua with a module called "foo", but when I call `require("foo")` in my Lua script, I get the error:

```
foo_test.lua:1: module 'foo' not found:
    no field package.preload['process']
    no file '!\lua\process.lua'
    no file '!\lua\process\init.lua'
    no file '!\process.lua'
    no file '!\process\
```

My Lua script:

```
foo.bar()
```

My lua_foo.h file:

```
#include <lua.h>
extern "C" int luaopen_foo( lua_State* L );
```

My lua_foo.cpp file:

```
#include "lua_foo.h"
#include <lua.hpp>

static int l_bar( lua_State *L )
{
    puts( "in bar()" );
    return 1;
}

int luaopen_foo( lua_State *L ) 
{
    static const luaL_Reg foo[] = {
        { "bar", l_bar },
        { NULL, NULL }
    };

    luaL_newlib( L, foo );
    return 1;
}
```

These are compiled in to a static library "lua_foo.lib" which is statically linked to my main Lua executable.

Can anybody help me understand where I'm going wrong? thanks. I would prefer to avoid c++ wrappers (for now) and I do not want to package this library as a separate DLL from the main Lua engine.

---

**EDIT**

The issue was in the lua engine code. I added the `luaL_requiref` per @NicolBolas 's suggestion.

```
lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
if( NULL != L )
{
    luaL_openlibs( L );
    luaL_requiref( token.get(), "foo", luaopen_foo, 1 );
    luaL_dofile( L, "foo_test.lua" );
    lua_close( L );
}
```

Comment: Why is everybody that submits an answer to this question getting modded down?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's important to understand how the `require` machinery works and therefore why your code doesn't.

`require` is designed to look for Lua scripts in the file system and ***DLLs***. Static libraries are not DLLs; indeed, as far as C/C++ is concerned, once you've finished linking, static libraries are no different than compiling those .c/.cpp files into your application directly.

When `require` finds a DLL with the appropriate name, it loads it and attempts to find a function named `luaopen_<modname>`, where `<modname>` is the name of the module. When it does, it will execute this function and store the value it returns in an internal database of loaded modules.

Calling `require` for a module will return whatever this function returned; if the module has already been loaded, then the return value is pulled from the database and returned directly.

Simply calling `luaopen_foo` will *not do any of this*. Indeed, simply calling this function is a bad idea; it is a Lua function and needs to be called *as a Lua function* (ie: you need to push it onto the Lua stack with `lua_pushcfunction` and call it with `lua_call` and so forth).

If you want to create a *local* module (one not in a Lua script or DLL, but exposed from your code), then you need to use the Lua facilities to do that. Specifically, use `luaL_requiref`:

```
luaL_requiref(L, "foo", luaopen_foo, 0);
```

Call this instead of calling `luaopen_foo` directly. This will automatically register the return value from `luaopen_foo` with `require`'s internal database of loaded modules. Thus, subsequent calls to `require "foo"` will return this table.

One more thing: `do` is a *keyword* in Lua; you should not use keywords for Lua table key names. You *can*, but you always have to quote them (ie: your script must do `foo["do"](...)` to call it).

Comment: **"simply calling this function is a bad idea; it is a Lua function and needs to be called as a Lua function"**  This is nonsensical. It's a *C* function which just happens to take a `lua_State*` parameter and make Lua API calls, like hundreds of other functions in the Lua API. Lua doesn't call all it's own internal functions using `pushcfunction`. There's no advantage to doing it that way.

Comment: @Mud: No, it does matter. You *cannot* call `luaopen_base` or similar Lua library opening functions directly. The Lua documentation is ***very clear on this***. In 5.1, [it says you can't call it directly](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5). In 5.2, [it specifically says to call them through `luaL_requiref`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6).

Comment: Have you looked at the source of those functions? There's a reason they have to be call that way, which is utterly unrelated to the OP's code. There is nothing magical about a function which takes `lua_State*` that requires it be called via `lua_pushcfunction`, or the Lua API would be impossible.

Comment: @Mud: It doesn't matter what the source code is; the Lua documentation says to *not* call them directly. If you want to argue with the Lua documentation, feel free. I'm simply saying what *it* says. Also, Lua 5.1 once crashed on me when I called `luaopen_base` directly; that's why I know the rule.

Comment: The OP is *not* calling them directly, and his code is *not* one them. In fact, his code doesn't need a return value at all, and it *can* be called directly, and in my example code I actually *do* that. You're extrapolating from a totally unrelated example, incorrectly, because you don't know *why* the documentation says that about those functions. That's why I suggested you read it. It has nothing whatsoever to do with the OP's problem.

Comment: @Mud: It isn't unrelated. Functions you register with Lua expect to be called *from* Lua. Therefore, they are free to make certain assumptions about the `lua_State` and do certain things that only code called from Lua can do (like call `lua_error` and so forth). While his *current* implementation of `luaopen_foo` doesn't do any of these things, it *could* eventually. And it's best to make errors impossible wherever one can. As such, calling a function from C that you expect to register with Lua is a bad idea, period.

Comment: He didn't register the function with Lua. I'm addressing his code. You're addressing a hypothetical version of his code that doesn't exist.

Comment: I've updated my code (above) per the suggestions and added `luaL_requiref` I'm still getting `foo_test.lua:1: attempt to index global 'foo' (a nil value)`

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. The last parameter of `luaL_requiref` has to be set to `1` for Lua to store the module name as a global.

Answer (score 1):

- `luaopen_foo` creates a table with one function in it, but it doesn't expose it to Lua in any way. You need to assign it to something your scripts can access if you want to access it. You can do this with the package mechanism, or just assign it to a global (which is what Lua's built-in libraries do).
- You have a field named `do`, which is problematic if you want to use `foo.do` syntax, because `do` is a keyword.
- The return value of a Lua function tells Lua how many values you left on the stack. Your `l_do` function lies with its return value.
- In the case of `luaopen_foo`, since you're calling it directly and ignoring it's return value, there's no need for it to return anything at all.

Change your code to this:

```
static int l_bar( lua_State *L )
{
   puts("l_bar called.");
   return 0;
}

void luaopen_foo( lua_State *L ) 
{
   static const struct luaL_Reg foo[] = {
      { "bar", l_bar },
      { NULL, NULL }
   };
   luaL_newlib( L, foo );   // create table containing `bar`
   lua_setglobal(L, "foo"); // assign that table to global `foo`
}
```

And change your script to this:

```
foo.bar()
```

Comment: In my lua executable, I've added `luaopen_foo( L );` just after the `luaL_openlibs( L );` call. The error remains the same.

Comment: Yes, the error is because Lua cannot find `foo.dll`. If you're statically linking, you need to call `luaopen_foo` yourself and you need to *not* call `require('foo')`. Get rid of the `require` call.

Comment: Mud - Okay, now I get the error `foo_test.lua:1: attempt to index global 'foo' (a nil value)`. If I remove the `foo` prefix from `foo.do()` and just call `do()`, then I get the error `attempt to call global 'do' (a nil value)`

Comment: Because `foo` doesn't exist. You created a table containing your `do` function, but you don't do anything with it. You don't assign it to a global named `foo` at any point.

Comment: -1: for having a module directly modify the global table, which is generally considered bad practice these days.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: It was the simplest possible example (adding 1 line of code) to illustrate what the OP was missing, not a recommendation as a best practice. The point was that merely creating a table and leaving it on the stack isn't enough; you have to make that table visible to Lua.

Comment: @Mud: That's why he *returned* it. His idea was to register the returned table so that `require` would work for his module exactly as it did for a DLL or Lua script module. His code is fine; he simply didn't know how to call it correctly to make the connection for `require`.

Comment: Given how wrong his source was, on many levels, you're make a lot of assumptions. In particular, that he knew what he was doing and wasn't just following an example and couldn't figure out how it worked. Look at your fear of calling `lua_State*` functions  directly: that's because *you* don't understand how they work. But focusing on the simplest possible example, rather than jumping into Lua's module system, it may actually clarify how this shit works for him.

Comment: @Mud: I appreciate your help, but the preferred solution should be a best practice. Also, I added the `lua_setglobal` command and the program exited with a `PANIC` error from Lua.

Comment: Your panic is an unrelated issue (have to see your code to know what it is). The point of my example was not to show a best practice (I have no problem with your selected answer) but to *clarify* what your problem was (i.e. you *were* creating a table, but providing no way to access it). If it accomplished that, then it's all good.

Comment: should be `int luaopen_foo`… and then `return` the count of return values (can be zero), `void` function means Lua gets `<some garbage>` and then proceeds to pop `<some garbage>` number of values from the stack… anything can happen, including the `PANIC`.