# Why won't lua load my DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, lua

I get this error:

`FATAL ERROR:
lua_pcall() failed: error loading module 'foo' from file 'C:\Users\Commander\Desktop\Platform\Debug\foo.dll':
        The specified procedure could not be found.`

I load my DLL file in Lua:

```
require("foo")
```

My DLL code, I use Visual Studio Compiler
(It compiles, no errors)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#pragma comment( lib, "liblua53.a" )
extern "C" {
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
}

#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    static int l_bar(lua_State *L)
    {
        puts("l_bar called.");
        return 0;
    }

    void luaopen_foo(lua_State *L)
    {
        static const struct luaL_Reg foo[] = {
        { "bar", l_bar },
            { NULL, NULL }
        };
        luaL_newlib(L, foo);  
        lua_setglobal(L, "foo"); 
    }
}
```

Is there anyway around this error, Or is it not possible to load dll files in lua

I found the example c++ code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12059441/8767704

Comment: You should export your function from this DLL.

Comment: The correct signature for a [luaopen](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_CFunction) function is `int (*lua_CFunction) (lua_State *L)`